# Here i want to display 3rows of mysql table in output. it shows 7errors how to solve this error? please tell

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Here i want to display 3rows of mysql table in output. it shows 7errors how to solve this error? please tell how to reactify the error. i am having 7 errors, i want to show mysql table. i need correct mysql query. Here i want to display 3rows of mysql table in output. it shows 7errors how to solve this error? please tell how to reactify the error. i am having 7 errors, i want to show mysql table. i need correct mysql query

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
/* Style the body */
body 
{
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
  margin: 0;
}
.header 
{
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] 
{
  width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) 
{
  /* For tablets: */
  .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-s-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-s-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-s-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-s-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) 
{
  /* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
.content {
  max-width: 1800px;
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
}
.button {
  width: 105px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ex1 {
  margin: 200px 120px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
  <h1>Report Table is given below..
</div>

<%@page import = "java.sql.DriverManager,java.sql.Connection,java.sql.Statement,java.sql.ResultSet,java.sql.SQLException, java.util.Vector" %>
   <%
      Statement stmt = null;
      Connection con = null;
      ResultSet rsT = null;

      boolean errFlag = false;
      String str = null;
      
      String sdbName, sregion,sregion1,sregion2,
      sdbName = request.getParameter("scaleup");
      sregion = request.getParameter("region");
      sregion1 = request.getParameter("region1");
      sregion2 = request.getParameter("region2");
          
      int result=0;
      
      try
      {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/" + sdbName,"root","");
         stmt = con.createStatement();
       
        //System.out.println("select * from scaleupdata where sregion= '" + region + "' and sregion1='" + region1 + "' and sregion2='" + region2 + "'");           
        rsT = stmt.executeQuery("select * from scaleupdata where sregion= '" + region + "' and sregion1='" + region1 + "' and sregion2='" + region2 + "'");
        
        if(rsT.next())
        {
            result=0;
            result= rsT.getInt(1);
            result= rsT.getInt(2);
            result= rsT.getInt(3);
            
            <table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>region</th>
            <th>region1</th>
            <th>region2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><%result=rst.getInt(1);%></td>
            <td><%result=rst.getInt(2);%></td>
            <td><%result=rst.getInt(3);%></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
                
        }       
        rsT.close();
        
        System.out.println("result  "+result);
        
        if(result==1)
        {
            str = "<center><h2>You Have Entered Invalid details</h2></center>";
                    
        }
         else 
            {
                
            %><jsp:forward page="Login.jsp"/>;<%
                
            } 
            
        stmt = null;
        con = null;
        rsT = null;
      }
      catch(SQLException sqle)
      {
         str = "<h2>Error : " + sqle + "</h2>"; 
           errFlag = true;
      }
%>  


<p><%=str%></p>

</body>
</html>

Generated servlet error:
    [javac] Since fork is true, ignoring compiler setting.
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file
    [javac] Since fork is true, ignoring compiler setting.
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Tomcat 4.1\work\Standalone\localhost\_\SCALEUP\report_jsp.java:91: illegal start of expression
    [javac]             
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Tomcat 4.1\work\Standalone\localhost\_\SCALEUP\report_jsp.java:68: sdbName is already defined in _jspService(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
    [javac]       sdbName = request.getParameter("scaleup");
    [javac]       ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Tomcat 4.1\work\Standalone\localhost\_\SCALEUP\report_jsp.java:82: cannot resolve symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable region  
    [javac] location: class org.apache.jsp.report_jsp
    [javac]         rsT = stmt.executeQuery("select * from scaleupdata where sregion= '" + region + "' and sregion1='" + region1 + "' and sregion2='" + region2 + "'");
    [javac]                                                                                        ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Tomcat 4.1\work\Standalone\localhost\_\SCALEUP\report_jsp.java:82: cannot resolve symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable region1  
    [javac] location: class org.apache.jsp.report_jsp
    [javac]         rsT = stmt.executeQuery("select * from scaleupdata where sregion= '" + region + "' and sregion1='" + region1 + "' and sregion2='" + region2 + "'");
    [javac]                                                                                                                      ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Tomcat 4.1\work\Standalone\localhost\_\SCALEUP\report_jsp.java:82: cannot resolve symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable region2  
    [javac] location: class org.apache.jsp.report_jsp
    [javac]         rsT = stmt.executeQuery("select * from scaleupdata where sregion= '" + region + "' and sregion1='" + region1 + "' and sregion2='" + region2 + "'");
    [javac]                                                                                                                                                     ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Tomcat 4.1\work\Standalone\localhost\_\SCALEUP\report_jsp.java:101: cannot resolve symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable rst  
    [javac] location: class org.apache.jsp.report_jsp
    [javac] result=rst.getInt(2);
    [javac]        ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Tomcat 4.1\work\Standalone\localhost\_\SCALEUP\report_jsp.java:104: cannot resolve symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable rst  
    [javac] location: class org.apache.jsp.report_jsp
    [javac] result=rst.getInt(3);
    [javac]        ^
    [javac] 7 errors
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is the comma at the end of the String declaration instead of semicolon.

```
String sdbName, sregion,sregion1,sregion2,
```

Try

```
String sdbName, sregion, sregion1, sregion2;
```

On the query you are using variables that are not declared (you declared them with an s char at the beginning but you try to use them without the s):

```
rsT = stmt.executeQuery("select * from scaleupdata where sregion= '" + region + "' and sregion1='" + region1 + "' and sregion2='" + region2 + "'");
```

Try

```
rsT = stmt.executeQuery("select * from scaleupdata where sregion= '" + sregion + "' and sregion1='" + sregion1 + "' and sregion2='" + sregion2 + "'");
```

It can also be related to some copied text from web which has some strange character/formatting.

Try to cut all the code, paste it on text editor like notepad++ and then copy it again and paste it back in your IDE.

Comment: still same error

Comment: You are trying to use undeclared variable. You forgot the s at the beginning. I updated the answer.